# Lightning force:recordView Edit Event on Pencil Icon Click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, view, edit

The `force:recordView` Lightning component shows pencil icon edit buttons next to each field, however clicking them doesn't appear to do anything and there's [no documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm) on how to catch a click from them.

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.selectedCaseId}" type="FULL"/>
```

Shows:

[image]

How do we catch a click event on those edit buttons?

Comment: This should be reported as a bug, the recordview component should be a read only component as per docs "A force:recordView component represents a read-only view of a record." It should not show the edit pencil icon when used inside an object detail/ pagelayout. If you want to provide edit access you can instead use force:recordData instead of recordview